# Solving a general 2 variable system of eq.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Hello guys i'm trying to derive a general formula for something and this is the system of equations i get. I'm hoping to get a simple and beautiful solutions but i fail. The solution i got my elimination was

$$q-l=a(p^2-k^2)+b(p-k)$$

but this yields an answer for $a+b$  and i want to get a solution for only $a$ and only $b$. I tried to use substitution but the answer yielded was really long and ugly. Could you please look over this and write whether it has good answers or not. Here's the system:

$$q=ap^2-am^2+bp-bm+n$$
$$l=ak^2-am^2+bk-bm+n$$

Comment: What do you mean a solution for only $a$ and $b$? Like $a = \ldots$ and $b = \ldots$?

Comment: Yes exactly. Couldnt formulate it properly, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try solving for $a$ in terms of $b$ in the first equation, and then plug that into the second equation. For example:

$q = a(p^2-m^2)+b(p-m)+n$, so $a(p^2-m^2)=q - b(p-m) - n$, and $a = \frac{q-b(p-m)-n}{p^2-m^2}$.

Plug $a$ into the second equation now.

$l = a(k^2-m^2)+b(k-m)+n=\frac{q-b(p-m)-n}{p^2-m^2}(k^2-m^2)+b(k-m)+n$

Now you have $b(k-m) = l-n-\frac{q-b(p-m)-n}{p^2-m^2}(k^2-m^2)$, and $b = l-n-\frac{q-b(p-m)-n}{(p^2-m^2)(k-m)}(k^2-m^2)$

There are simplifications you can do along the way, I'm just doing the straight forward approach. Plug $b$ into the equation for $a$ and you'll get some mess that you *should* be able to simplify.

Comment: I already did that, but substituting values only expanded the expression and i couldnt simplify it further. This is why i asked for help.

Comment: I'll write a little more then perhaps

Comment: Does that help a little?

Comment: Yes it does help. Ill do simplifications now. I guess i was tad lazy back when i was posting this.

Comment: We all are sometimes. Good luck! Edit your question with a solution when you're done